# How to get a corresponding key in a json object and put it in my recyclerView onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have a json array, `jsonArray`, like:

```
[{
        "phone_number": "+123456",
        "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "phone_number": "+234567",
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "phone_number": "+345678",
        "name": "Jim"
    },
    {
        "phone_number": "+4567890",
        "name": "Jane"
    },
    {
        "phone_number": "+5678901",
        "name": "Sally"
    }
]
```

In my `onBindViewHolder` I want to check if `phone_number` value in the `json array` matches `username` and then if there is a match then in the `viewHolder.phone_user_name` set the text to the corresponding value in `"name"` of the json array.

But all I get in my `recyclerView` for each cell is `user : (blank)`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        SharedReview r = the_Shared_reviews.get(position);

        //username is in fact a phone number from the db
        String username = r.getUsername();

        String phone_user_name = "";

        int matching = jsonArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < matching; i++) {

            try {

                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (object.getString("phone_number").contains(username))

                {

                    phone_user_name = (object.getString("name"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
            }
        }


            //I want to set the text to Bob, Tom, or whatever corresponding
            // phone number matches username
            ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setText("user :" + phone_user_name);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a list of Object of (Phone Number, Name) and bind it to the recycler view. in "onBindViewHolder()", you can find the corresponding object from the list which contains both fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what value is supposed to be in the SharedReview class under the username variable, but I'm assuming it's a name, not a number.

However, you are testing if your json array item named "phone_number", which in your example is an actual phone number, contains the username. Which is assumably a name.

You should replace:

```
    if (object.getString("phone_number").contains(username))

            {

                phone_user_name = (object.getString("name"));
            }
```

With:

```
    if (object.getString("name").equals(username))

            {

                phone_user_name = (object.getString("name"));
            }
```